# Get image from DIV which contains SVG elements with background images

Tags: canvas, svg

Is it possible to get an image of DIV element which contains SVG elements with background images inside. Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3319/) of SVG with background image and script which unfortunately doesn't save image of SVG elements.

```
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Two external resources from nihilogic.dk results in 404. Also keep in mind HTTPS when referrencing external resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to PNG with applied images as background to svg elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042910/convert-svg-to-png-with-applied-images-as-background-to-svg-elements)

Comment: Also, if IE<Edge support is not an issue, you may have a look at [SVG2Bitmap.js](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap) that you can call before `html2canvas`. (disclaimer: I wrote it).