# Drawing SVG Image to Canvas showing up blank

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I have an SVG tag. Upon clicking of a button a dynamically create an SVG Image inside the SVG tag.

```
var svgimg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'height','450');
svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'width','845');
svgimg.setAttribute('class', 'dragImage');
svgimg.addEventListener("mousedown", dragFunc);
svgimg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', '/images/dog.jpg');
$('#svg').append(svgimg);
```

Works beautifully. Then, with the click of a different button, I am taking that SVG, and converting it to a Canvas.

```
 var svgContent= document.querySelector('svg').innerHTML;

var img = new Image();


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
img.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

}
 img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+btoa(svgContent);
```

However, this  shows up blank, empty. No image. If i manually set the img.src to

```
    img.src = "images/dog.jpg";
```

This will work fine and write to my Canvas. Im guessing it has something to do with the SVG Image type? Here is the HTML:

```
   <div id="parentDiv">
   <svg id='svg' width="845" height="450" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
   </div>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

Any help would be great. Essentially, I want to know, why the newly created Image for my Canvas would draw the 'data:image/svg+xml;base64', Am i converting something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to PNG with applied images as background to svg elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042910/convert-svg-to-png-with-applied-images-as-background-to-svg-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following:

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
svg.remove();

// write serialized svg to canvas
canvg('canvas', svg_xml, {useCORS: true});

// create canvas data on demand
function downloadCanvas() {
    this.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};
document.getElementById('imgId').addEventListener('click', downloadCanvas, false);
```