# Download SVG with images

Tags: javascript, image, svg

I want to download an SVG image in my DOM. I've searched around on stack overflow and the common approach to do this is following these steps:

**Serialize the svg to a XML string**

```
var svgImage = document.getElementById('maskedImage')
var svgXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svgImage)
```

**Create a javascript Image with the XML string as a source**

```
var img = new Image();
var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

img.onload = function () {
    /* next steps go here */
}

img.src = url;
```

**Draw that Image on a canvas**

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, width, height)
```

**Dump the canvas to an URL and make the user download that**

```
window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))  // not the point of the question
```

---

The thing is, my SVG has an `<image>` tag with an SVG mask (which is a black and white `<image>`). To make things worse, one of these images has an object URL (those returned by `URL.createObjectUrl(...)`). These are requirements and cannot be changed.

Following the mentioned process, the initial SVG "looses" images on the second step. The image `img` doesn't display the `<image>`, even if I remove the mask and display.

I've also tried removing the mask and changing the `<image>` url from something created with `URL.createObjectURL` to an inline image (`data:image/png;base64,...`), to a dummy URL (`http://www.tuvotacion.com/imagenes_unicas/cual-perrito-es-mas-tierno-450089.jpg`) and I'm still not able to display images.

---

Note that this question is not a duplicate of all the questions asking how to download an SVG, but a special case when you have images.

## The question

How can I "translate" my SVG to an image without loosing `<image>`s, so I can effectively print it on the canvas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to PNG with applied images as background to svg elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042910/convert-svg-to-png-with-applied-images-as-background-to-svg-elements)

Comment: base64 encode all your `<image>` tags before serializing your svg.

Comment: @Salketer my question takes that into account (see 'the common approach' part). There are tons of questions which ask the same, but my problem is a specific case for which the answer of those questions fails.

Comment: @Kaiido interesting ideas, I will try them now.

Comment: @Kaiido base64 encoding all images worked. Post it as a answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Well that's already the content in my answer to the duplicate question I did link to. I would rather prefer you to accept this dupe.